# Collapse tableView rows on a row select in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, tableview

i have a tableView where i show user created circle name and i want when the user select a circle name rest circle name collapse and show only one circle name. but i don't know how to do that. please help help me guys.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if indexPath.section == 0
    {
        // here is the code to collapse the row
    }      
 }
```

Section == 0 have the rows of circle names.

Comment: What is a "circle name"?

Comment: Means you want like a expandable list which can be collapsed on click...right?

Comment: yes @GouravJoshi

Comment: Circle Name is a list of data @d4Rk

Comment: [Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/) will help you.

Comment: I also implemented this case but my own way....wait for few mins...I will share my code snippet...

Comment: this tutorial used xib but i want to do that without xib. @byJeevan

Comment: Ok and Thanks @GouravJoshi

Comment: @Innate Please check the answer the code is lengthy, however it works for me...

Comment: Expand cell up to bottom part of view.so disable scrolling if you don't want user to show other rows. to show back again all rows you can put button in expanded row so by tapping that change height to default  and make scrolling enable.

Comment: @Innate edited the code check it out

Comment: @Innate check edit-2 of my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can do like below, to collapse the other cell, except the selected cell, for this create a new file lets call it as `CustomCell.swift` and make it a subclass if `UITableViewCell` and add the below code.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var circleNameTextField: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var holderView: UIView!
  var cellindexPath:IndexPath?
  var selectedIndexPath:IndexPath?

  func animateCell() {
      if self.selectedIndexPath?.row == self.cellindexPath?.row {
          return
      } else {
         let isUpword = (cellindexPath!.row > selectedIndexPath!.row)
        self.animateCellWithDirection(upWord: isUpword)
      }
 }

 func animateCellWithDirection(upWord:Bool) {
     var hideRect = self.bounds
     if upWord {
         hideRect.origin.y = -hideRect.size.height
     } else {
         hideRect.origin.y = hideRect.size.height
     }

     UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations:{
       self.holderView.frame = hideRect
     })
  }   
}
```

and  you need to create a add a prototype cell in storyboard like below, screen

[image]

and set the class name to  `CustomCell` as shown, and in the attribute inspector set the reuse identifier like below screen, and one more thing add a view called `holderView` to cell's content view and add label inside the `holderView` and create a `outlet` in customCell as shown in the below image, see the view hierarchy, inside content view there is one more view and it contains the subview as `UILabel` circle name label.

[image]

now in the ViewController.swift add below code,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var aTableView: UITableView!
var selIndexPath:IndexPath?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
      //self.aTableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CUSTOM_CELL")

   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      self.selIndexPath = indexPath
      self.aTableView.reloadData()
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return 5
   }

   func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      return 1
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell : CustomCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CUSTOM_CELL", for: indexPath) as? CustomCell//tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CUSTOM_CELL") as? CustomCell

       cell?.circleNameTextField.text = "Circle Name"

       cell?.cellindexPath = indexPath

       if let selectedIndexPath = self.selIndexPath {
          cell?.selectedIndexPath = selectedIndexPath
          cell?.animateCell()
       }

       return cell!
   }

}
```

if want try out in separate project, i posted the entire code
and final result something like below,

[image]

**Edit:--)**
in the question u asked, `when the user select a circle name rest circle name collapse and show only one circle name` thats why i did like above, any way, hear is the modification to `ViewController.swift` class, just define an array called `dataSourceArray` which holds all the circle name to be displayed in the table view,

```
 let dataSourceArray = ["Circle Name_1","Circle Name_2","Circle Name_3","Circle Name_4","Circle Name_5"]
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //self.aTableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CUSTOM_CELL")

 }
```

and edit the below methods, like below

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.selIndexPath = indexPath
    self.aTableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .fade)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return ((self.selIndexPath) != nil) ?  1 : dataSourceArray.count
 }

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : CustomCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CUSTOM_CELL", for: indexPath) as? CustomCell//tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CUSTOM_CELL") as? CustomCell

    cell?.cellindexPath = indexPath

    if let selectedIndexPath = self.selIndexPath {
        cell?.selectedIndexPath = selectedIndexPath
        cell?.circleNameTextField.text = dataSourceArray[selectedIndexPath.row]
       // cell?.animateCell()
    } else {
       // cell?.resetCellWith(animate:false)
         cell?.circleNameTextField.text = dataSourceArray[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell!
}
```

in the method `.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .fade)` u can change the animation type according to requirement.

Hope above works as your  requirement :)

**Edit:2**

for the above code,
just add a member variable, which controls expand and collapse of the cells,

```
    var expandCell:Bool = false //initially is false
```

and just replace with below methods,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.expandCell = !expandCell
    if self.expandCell {
        self.selIndexPath = indexPath
    } else {
        self.selIndexPath = nil;
    }

    self.aTableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .fade)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if self.expandCell {
        return ((self.selIndexPath) != nil) ?  1 : dataSourceArray.count
    } else {
        return dataSourceArray.count
    }
}
```

Comment: it hides only circle name i want to hide rows and show only selected row

Comment: Ok. I will Check. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks it Works Good.

Comment: Is there anyway to expand these circle names when i tap again on selected circle name.

Comment: can u help me to do that

Answer (score 1):

First I have make a structure for managing Expand collapse feature.
All Macros:

```
let IndexVal = -4
let ISSELECTED = "ISSELECTED"
let SELECTED = "SELECTED"
let UNSELECTED = "UNSELECTED"
let FLAGE = "FLAGE"
let DATA = "DATA"
```

I create an array  `arrTA = NSMutableArray()` in which our whole processed data will be stored.
here I have used arrFolderList in which the JSON data is storing.

Now when you call an API and in that response you need to call this function with `IndexVal`

```
 self.reloadTableForExpandCollapse(IndexVal)
```

This will set the default view i.e collpased view.

And use it in this way:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.reloadTableForExpandCollapse(indexPath.row)
    }
```

Now function defination:

```
func reloadTableForExpandCollapse( indexValue: Int)  {
        var index = indexValue
        if(index == IndexVal) {  /// This is the case when we run first time
            arrTA = NSMutableArray()
            for i in 0..<self.arrFolderList.count {
                let strFlage = "MA"
                let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
                dict.setObject(strFlage, forKey: FLAGE)
                dict.setObject(UNSELECTED, forKey: ISSELECTED)
                dict.setObject(self.arrFolderList[i] , forKey: DATA)
                arrTA.addObject(dict)
            }
        } else { /// When we are performing the operations
            /// When we collapsed
             if(index == IndexVal) {
            arrTA = NSMutableArray()
            for i in 0..<self.arrFolderList.count {
                let strFlage = "MA"
                let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
                dict.setObject(strFlage, forKey: FLAGE)
                dict.setObject(UNSELECTED, forKey: ISSELECTED)
                dict.setObject(self.arrFolderList[i], forKey: DATA)
                arrTA.addObject(dict)
            }
                self.tblView_Expandable.reloadData()
             } else {

                if(index < arrTA.count) {
                    let dict = arrTA.objectAtIndex(index) as! NSMutableDictionary
                    dict.setObject(SELECTED, forKey: ISSELECTED)
                    let strFlage = dict[FLAGE] as! String
                    if(strFlage == "MA") { /// Means it is main array
                        var isAdding: Bool = true
                        var isRemoving: Bool = true
                        if (index  < self.arrTA.count) {
                            for var j in index + 1..<self.arrTA.count   {  /// removed + 1from index
                                let dict1 = self.arrTA[j]
                                let strFlage1 = (dict1[FLAGE] as! String)
                                if (strFlage1 == "SA") && isRemoving {
                                    isAdding = false
                                    dict[ISSELECTED] = UNSELECTED
                                    self.arrTA.removeObjectAtIndex(j)
                                    j -= 1
                                    break
                                } else if isAdding {
                                    isRemoving = false
                                      break
                                } else if (strFlage1 == "MA") && isRemoving {
                                      break
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if ((dict[FLAGE] as! String) == "MA") {
                            var k = 0
                            while k < self.arrTA.count {
                                let dict1 = self.arrTA[k] as! NSMutableDictionary
                                dict1[ISSELECTED] = UNSELECTED
                                let strFlage1 = (dict1[FLAGE] as! String)
                                if (strFlage1 == "SA") {
                                    self.arrTA.removeObjectAtIndex(k)
                                    if k < index {
                                        index -= 1
                                    }
                                    k -= 1
                                }
                                k += 1
                            }
                        }

                        if isAdding {
                            let dict = self.arrTA[index] as! NSMutableDictionary
                            let strFlage = (dict[FLAGE] as! String)
                            //  dict[ISSELECTED] = UNSELECTED
                            self.arrTA.replaceObjectAtIndex(index, withObject: dict)
                            if (strFlage == "MA") {
                                let dictData = (dict[DATA] as! NSDictionary)
                                let dictSA = NSMutableDictionary()
                                let strFlage = "SA"
                                dictSA[FLAGE] = strFlage
                                dictSA[DATA] = dictData
                                dictSA[ISSELECTED] = UNSELECTED
                                self.arrTA.insertObject(dictSA, atIndex: index + 1)
                            }
                            if(self.tblView_Expandable.lastIndexpath().row == index) {
                               self.scrollTableViewToBottom()
                            }
                        }
                    }else {  }
                    }
                }
            }
        if(tblView_Expandable != nil) {
                 tblView_Expandable.reloadData()
        }

      }
```

And I hope this will help.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Custom other cell for collapsed circel name cell.
such as CollapsedCell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "kCollapsedCell", for: indexPath) as CollapsedCell {
            cell.doSomething()
        }
    }
}
```